# How to create a sequence of pandas dataframes using a for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have information in different dataframes related to several securities. I would like to be able to run a loop where I take the columns I need from different dataframes and I create one dataframe per security with the columns I need and then I store the dataframes as elements of a dictionary, something along the following lines:

```
securities={}
for tick in tickers:
    df_'tick' = pd.Dataframe(data,columns['a','b','c'])
    securities[tick] = df_tick
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
securities = { tick : pd.Dataframe(data,columns['a','b','c'])
    for tick in tickers:

}
```